# How to retrieve month and year value when user click on month navigation in mat-calendar?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, calendar

I am using  in my Angular Project. I wanted to catch the event and get the month and year value when user click on navigation button at top for changing month.

[image]

After a lot of search I managed to get following piece of code to grab the click event. I am not able to get the month and year value. How to get it?

**HTML**

```
<mat-calendar [minDate]="minDate" [maxDate]="maxDate" [dateClass]="dateClass()" [dateFilter]="futureEventFilter"
            #calendar (monthSelected)="monthSelected($event)" (selectedChange)="getDateChangedValue($event)" [(selected)]="selectedDate">
        </mat-calendar>
```

**TS Code**

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
        let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('mat-calendar .mat-calendar-previous-button,' +
            'mat-calendar .mat-calendar-next-button');
    
        if (buttons) {
            Array.from(buttons).forEach(button => {
                this.renderer.listen(button, "click", () => {
                    //this.monthSelected($event);
                    console.log(button)
                });
            })
        }
    }

public monthSelected(date) {
        alert(date);
    }
```

How to call monthSelected and retrieve month and year value?
Please help here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57510066/how-can-i-catch-the-material-datepicker-month-pagination-event/60297741#60297741

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

You can do something like this:

```
<mat-calendar [selected]="selectedDate" (selectedChange)="logMonth($event)"></mat-calendar>
```

And a handler for your selectedChange in your ts file:

```
  selectedDate: any
  logMonth($event: any) {
    this.selectedDate = $event
    console.log($event)
  }
```

You will have the date printed in the console, and the calendar updated with the selected date

**Original:**

Use `mat-datepicker` instead: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-75eqqf?file=src/app/datepicker-api-example.html)

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
    <mat-datepicker (monthSelected)="logMonth($event)" #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
<button mat-raised-button (click)="picker.open()">Open</button>
```

You don't need the whole `ngAfterViewInit() {...}` block of code.
All you need `(monthSelected)="logMonth($event)"` in your date picker, and `logMonth($event)` in your ts file to handle the event:

```
  logMonth($event: any) {
    console.log($event);
  }
```

Comment: the `(monthselect)` only handle the event when you "click" the month, not when you're moving thougth the calendar

Comment: @Eliseo so you want something a hover event ?

Comment: No, I think, the question is about when change the month displayed, e.g. to call an api to change the class in some days. I put one link to SO to solve the problem in the question of simpleuser

Comment: My requirement is to show calendar to user instead of asking them to click on button to open datepicker. Hope it is clear. That is why I have used mat-calendar but now I am not able to select the month in calendar view. Please help me here.

Comment: so you want the callendar to be always visible!

Comment: @simpleuser I edited my answer maybe it is gobba be useful for you now. I edited the live demo too.

Comment: I used (selectedChange) as you have mentioned but it didnt get trigger when month navigation is clicked. It gets only triggered when I select date in the calendar.