# Angular mat calendar header arrow event

Tags: angular, angular-material, calendar

I need to capture the event when I click the mat calendar header arrow (both left and right) and attached the image below as well

[image]

demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qgy8qo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.ts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I catch the Material Datepicker month pagination event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57510066/how-can-i-catch-the-material-datepicker-month-pagination-event)

Comment: Hi @Bansi29 In that question they have done for mat-date picker not for angular calendar. I am expecting the same thing for the Angular calendar

Comment: It's the same, only use in mat-calendar tag

Comment: Can u give me some stackblitz working solution with mat-calendar to capture the arrow events?

Comment: No actually it is not mat calendar tag. In that example they have opened the calendar in the date picker that is different one