# Angular Material Datepicker DateClass

Tags: angular, angular-material

How can i update dateClass manually in a function?
[datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnnKM.png)

HTML

```
<mat-datepicker
    [dateClass]="dateClass"
    #picker
    fxLayoutAlign="start start"
    (opened)="appendFooter()"
  >
  </mat-datepicker>
```

TS

```
dateClass: MatCalendarCellClassFunction<Date> = (cellDate, view) => {
...
};
```

Comment: Can you explain more on how you would like to update it?

Comment: While the datepicker is opened I want to change / update dateClass. Currently this js only possible by opening and closing the datepicker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had some weird behaviour in my application that was faking the result. I fixed it. My final solution:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.mat-calendar-body-cell-content'); 
elements.forEach((x) => {let day: number = parseInt(x.textContent);
```

In the end i read the numbers in the calendar and compared them with a date. Its not the best solution but it works.

Thanks to @Eliseo for the right idea with the linked solution

Comment: This is a good solution as far as getting the dates but to retrieve the month and year, no so good.

Comment: You can try this to revice information from the picker:
`<mat-datepicker [dateClass]="setClass()"></mat-datepicker>`

Answer (score 1):

One aproach can be you binding the `dateclass` to a function that return a function (date: Date)=>string|null)

Imagine some like

```
dateClass(type:any) {
    switch (type)
    {
       case 0:
         return (date: Date): MatCalendarCellCssClasses => {
           ...
         }
         break
       case 1:
         return (date: Date): MatCalendarCellCssClasses => {
           ...
         }
         break
}
```

You can to have a variable type and use

```
 <mat-datepicker [dateClass]="dateClass(type)">...</mat-datepicker>
```

But take account that the "dateClass" function is executed only when you open the datepicker or when you change the month (one time for each day)

I feel you're looking for some like this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57510066/how-can-i-catch-the-material-datepicker-month-pagination-event/60297741#60297741). Well, you can take the aproach and call to the function "changeMonth" when you make a click

Comment: i was looking at something like your link, but its sadly to old and outdated. I want the "dateClass" function executed after a service of mine recieves data. But thanks!